# How to distinguish vector space from $k$-algebra?

Tags: commutative-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra with no nilpotents. What do I need to show in order to prove it's a finite dimensional vector space over $k$?

For example, is it enough to show that $A$ has only finitely prime ideals and every prime ideal is maximal?

Comment: Yes, in fact that's equivalent (and requiring every prime to be maximal is enough)

Comment: over nonclosed field?
I thought that is true, but understood that I have some problems in non-closed case

Comment: @user115654: Could you please explain why or give a reference to a book?

Comment: @pumpam: Atiyah-Macdonald, Exercise 8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A finitely generated commutative $k$-algebra $A$ is finite dimensional as a $k$-vector space exactly when it is artinian.

Proof: finite-dimensional implies artinian is essentially trivial (each ideal is also a vector subspace, and there are finitely many of them). For the other direction, pick generators for $A$, ie a surjective homomorphism $p:k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to A$. Then as $A$ is artinian, $p(\prod x_i^{n_i})=p(\prod x_i^{n_i+1})=0$ for some collection of $n_i$. But then we have a composition series for $A$ with all sections finite dimensional vector spaces, so $A$ is a finite dimensional vector space. $\blacksquare$

So any condition implying a ring is artinian will work. So for example requiring every prime ideal to be maximal will work.